# Disallow dynamic URL in robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt

Our URL is:

```
http://example.com/kitchen-knife/collection/maitre-universal-cutting-boards-rana-parsley-chopper-cheese-slicer-vegetables-knife-sharpening-stone-ham-stand-ham-stand-riviera-niza-knives-block-benin.html
```

I want to disallow URLs to be crawled after `collection`, but before `collection` there are categories that are dynamically coming.

How would I disallow URLs in robots.txt after `/collection`?

Comment: Disallow: /foloder_name/.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in the original robots.txt specification.

But some (!) parsers extend the specification and define a wildcard character (typically `*`).

For those parsers, you could use:

```
Disallow: /*/collection
```

Parsers that understand `*` as wildcard will stop crawling any URL whose path starts with *anything* (which may be *nothing*), followed by `/collection/`, followed by *anything*, e.g.,

```
http://example.com/foo/collection/
http://example.com/foo/collection/bar
http://example.com/collection/
```

Parsers that don’t understand `*` as wildcard (i.e., they follow the original specification) will stop crawling any URL whose paths starts with `/*/collection/`, e.g.

```
http://example.com/*/collection/
http://example.com/*/collection/bar
```